# order evaluation pre and post iterator increment

Tags: c++, iterator, increment

I am sorry. I should change my question. I have the following code

```
std::vector<int> v = {10, 20, 30};
auto it = v.begin();

std::cout << *it++ << std::endl;    // 1. no parenthesis

std::cout << *(it++) << std::endl;  // 2. with parenthesis

it++;                               // 3. post-increment first
std::cout << *it << std::endl; 

std::cout << *(it + 1) << std::endl;// 4. increment index
```

What is the difference between the above 4 statements? Is the parenthesis matter in post increment? All outputs are the same as my expectations except 2(with parenthesis).

Comment: In this case think on what the ++ operator returns, not when it is evaluated.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: With `*(it++)` you are dereferencing the old value of `it`.  With `*(++it)` you would be dereferencing the new value of `it`.

Comment: There is no difference between `*(it++)` and `*it++`. `(*it)++` *is* different, but would produce the same output in this case.

Comment: In case you can't solve the specific answers from the duplicate: #1 and #2 mean the same thing. #3 is the same as `std::cout << *++it << std::endl;` (see why?) #4 gives the same value as #3 to `cout`, but doesn't advance `it` to the next element.